# How to change encoding while doing queries in Django

Tags: python, django

There is this model:

```
class Currency(CustomBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=10)
```

There are two items in the database:

```
1. сум
2. у.e
```

These are russian characters. I am doing a simple filter:

```
Currency.objects.filter(name="сум")
```

It returns an empty list. I think the problem with encoding.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Django works with unicode. Try `Currency.objects.filter(name=u"сум")`

Answer (score 0):

try put this line at the top of your source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```